# How can reload display of Ribbon in VSTO?

Tags: vsto

I want display `Button2` while `Button1` processing.

This is my code: I using   `Application.DoEvents()` , But it can't

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As RibbonControlEventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Button2.Visible = True
        Globals.Ribbons.Ribbon1.RibbonUI.Invalidate()
        Application.DoEvents()

        Dim WB = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook
        For iSheet = 1 To WB.Sheets.Count
            Dim oSheet = WB.Sheets(iSheet)
            For irow = 1 To 1000
                If bStop Then
                    Exit For
                End If
                For icol = 1 To 20
                    If bStop Then
                        Exit For
                    End If
                    oSheet.Cells(irow, icol).Value = "Cell" & irow & icol
                Next
            Next
        Next

        Button2.Visible = False


    End Sub
```

How can reload display of Ribbon in VSTO?

Comment: What does "reload" mean? Do you want to update text/images/visibility/etc.? Or provide totally different ribbon?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko : I want display Button2 while Button1 processing.

Answer (score 0):

Add `getVisible` callback on `Button2`. When you call `RibbonUI.Invalidate()`, it will invoke your `getVisible` callback, and you can return the desired value from it (true or false).

Comment: Maybe, I have to use multithreading.

Comment: I am not sure what multithreading has to do with this - ribbon controls may and should only be accessed on the main thread.